# Setup Java development environment with Docker

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, docker

The last couple of days I spend a lot of time digging into docker. I'm really impressed about the possibility to have a environment within development that could be the same as in production!

At the moment I want to start small and begin to enhance the development process. We are developing Java Applications which are deployed on tomcat. The developers are using IDEs like Eclipse and IntelliJ.

During development you configure your tomcat environment within the IDE so you can automatically deploy and debug your code. Therefore the tomcat base directory has to be available to setup.

Currently I have a docker debian image with tomcat installed on /opt/tomcat.

I was now hoping to be able to link the contents of the containers /opt/tomcat directory to an directory within my host. 
Sadly that feature doesn't seem to exist. With the -v option you can only mount a host directory within the container and not the other way around.

Currently the only solution I see would be mounting the webapps directory of the container and drop my war file in here, which is in my point of view pretty unproductive.

You have to start/restart your tomcat manually, only remote debugging is possible, you don't have your logs within your IDE console.

So, does anyone has any idea on optimise the development workflow of Java Webapp development using docker?

Comment: This still does not look like it has a real solution in sight. I get that docker is fantastic for isolating environments and all but I really wish we could use a native IDE debugger, not the remote debugger when developing on a local  docker container. I don't want to have to sit there and redeploy my app every time i make a change to a jsp or some java class, it's inefficient.

Comment: I'm completely with you. I want to configure my runtime environment within my IDE and and also get the logs to my console without the need of manually packaging the software.

Comment: In my experience the easiest way to run a docker + tomcat setup is to use an embedded tomcat. So instead of running a tomcat and deploy a war file  you create a far jar containing the tomcat and running it instead. The main benefit is: You debug/run the same setup in development and production and it is extremely easy to create a docker image. I use spring-boot for the boilerplate stuff but that is optional. It is also implementable with just maven. Would you be interested in such a setup?

Comment: I've written Docker Shell - http://dockershell.io/ for this purpose. Unfortunately, it doesn't support running X applications yet, so you're still stuck with remote debugging.

Comment: Can you add the environment information in question ? What is your host for IDE ? Mac/Windows or Linux , it will impact the solution a lot. I can give  a solution if it is windows

Answer (score 2):

I saw a [blog](http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2015/06/15/Docker-meets-the-IDE) which was talking about doclipser (Eclipse + Docker).

Within the blog, primarily at the bottom of the post, it mentioned the following tools:

- [doclipser](https://www.github.com/domeide/doclipser)
- [Exlipse Docker Tooling (EDT)](http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2015-03-30-Eclipse_Docker_Tooling.html)
- [domeide.github.io](https://domeide.github.io/)
- [Sublime Docker](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Docker%20Based%20Build%20Systems)
- [IntelliJ IDEA 14.1](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/03/docker-support-in-intellij-idea-14-1/)
- [Eclipse JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2015-03-30-Eclipse_Docker_Tooling.html)
- [Visual Studio 2015 RC Tools for Docker](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f638067-027d-4817-bcc7-aa94163338f0) - As of 9/17/2015, this plugin hasn't been released yet.  But you should be able to preview extension.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You might have to run Eclipse and Tomcat in the same container, however I'd definitely try to get them to run in two separate containers first. Maybe start with this [base image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/fgrehm/eclipse/) and try to link it to a Tomcat image using a shared volume.

Comment: hey, installing the IDE within the same container is not an real option because I want to re-use the container also in production (in the future). I also really don't want to create a container for the IDE because the developer should use whatever IDE he wants with whatever OS he wants..

Comment: That's why I recommended the 2 container approach. That way you can link your Tomcat container to your IDE container in development only.

Comment: But I don't want to have the IDE within a container

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly, why not just use the `-v` option to mount the war file itself. This has worked okay for me using wildfly.

Basically, I use maven to build the war and map `target/myapp.war` to `/opt/wildfly/myapp.war`. Then, any time I make changes in the application I simply run mvn clean package and the app container, seeing that the war has changed, redeploys.

Now, this is taking advantage of wildfly's deployment scanner but might still work for tomcat as well. If not, maybe you could run tomcat with an exploded war and then just mount the build folder, target/myapp, into the webapps folder on tomcat.

Comment: In general you could use tomcat to automatically re-deploy but in real life this creates more problems than solves it..often leading to memory leaks or weird behaviour of the webapp...